# How can I increment the hours in a date based on an interval in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

**user input:**

```
dateinterval: 100714-10
interval: 2
```

**output**

```
datefrom: 07/10/2014 08:00
dateto: 07/10/2014 9:59
```

**user input:**

```
dateinterval: 100714-10
interval: 4
```

**output**

```
datefrom: 07/10/2014 06:00
dateto: 07/10/2014 9:59
```

The intervals will be 2,4,6,8,12,
there should be the difference of hours between `datefrom` and `dateto` depending on the interval chosen. For example, if the interval chosen is 2 then difference between the hours should be 2 hours. If the interval is 4 then the difference should be 4 hours.

the code i have written in button click

```
Protected Sub btnSubmitt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitt.Click
    Dim _DateTimeFormatInfo As New DateTimeFormatInfo()
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.LongDatePattern = "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern = "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthDayPattern = "MMMM dd"
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm "
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm"
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator = "/"
    _DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator = ""

    _DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    Dim strA As String = txtDateInterval.Text
    Dim split As String() = New String(strA.Length \ 2 + ((If(strA.Length Mod 2 = 0, 0, 1)) - 1)) {}

    For i As Integer = 0 To split.Length - 1

        split(i) = strA.Substring(i * 2, If(i * 2 + 2 > strA.Length, 1, 2))
    Next

    Dim s As String = split(0) & "/" & split(1) & "/" & split(2) & "" & split(3)
    Dim strIntervaltype As String = txtIntervalType.Text


    txtDateFrom.Text = DateTime.Parse(s, _DateTimeFormatInfo).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")

    txtDateTo.Text = DateTime.Parse(s, _DateTimeFormatInfo).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")      

End Sub
```

```
DateInterval  10072014-10      
IntervalType  2     
DateFrom      07/10/2014 08:00     
DateTo        07/10/2014 9:59
```

in the above the user will be giving the values dateinterval and intervaltype

```
DateFrom      07/10/2014 08:00     
DateTo        07/10/2014 9:59
```

how to get the above output

To get the desired output , what should I want to change

Comment: datefrom: 07/10/2014 06:00?

Comment: datefrom:07/10/2014 06:00

Comment: Edit your question.,

Comment: i have edited check it once

Answer (score 0):

You can simply proceed as below;

Firstly, convert your **dateinterval** into **datefrom**, which I think you are doing correctly.

Then using the **datefrom**, you just need to add the hours interval, as

```
dateto = datefrom.AddHours(interval)
```

your **dateto** will now add the hours interval to the **datefrom**. Saying that, I assume that the **datefrom** is correct. :)